# Where to get data for each WBAN ID and Station ID and its corresponding city

Tags: data-request, weather, noaa

I am trying to search for a dataset which contains WBAN id and Station ID for each weather station in New York and its corresponding city or county. I want this data set for my course project.

I want to map all the weather stations in New York into 5 boroughs of New York. The data I currently have has WBAN ID and the corresponding Counties. But the counties for half of the data is missing. Also, the data doesn't have corresponding Station IDS

Comment: Possibly helpful: http://www.weathergraphics.com/identifiers/master-location-identifier-database-20120801.txt and ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/isd-history.txt

Comment: Thanks, but I hate taking credit :) Go ahead and give it to the other answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This list from NOAA

http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/homr/file/emshr_lite.txt

has a bunch of station data for various networks (primarily WBAN and COOP) its a text file but it opens very nicely in excel with fixed width columns where you can sort based on the criteria you've specified. It includes counties for most stations and lat lon for all stations. Stations without a WBAN ID are part of a different network.

There's also this list from the EPA:

http://www2.epa.gov/sites/production/files/documents/STATION_LOCATIONS.PDF

Which only includes stations with a long history.

For future post include the data you already have.